# calling rmdir node_modules /S /Q from powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

Is it possible to call:

```
rmdir node_modules /S /Q
```

From powershell.  I get the dreaded path too long error with certain folders in powershell.  Using `rmdir` would get round this.

Comment: I usually work around that by renaming folders, which are too Long. That should also work from a PS perspective.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`rmdir` is a CMD builtin command. You can use it from PowerShell by calling `cmd.exe`:

```
& cmd /c rmdir node_modules /s /q
```

Comment: WOW! After many attempts with powershell Remove-Item (with and without Get-Children) this one works like a charm!! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I don't have powershell right here to test on this machine, but this command should be equivalent:

```
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse node_modules
```

Note that the `-Recurse` options sometimes doesn't work well.

So **If the previous fails** (likely?), you may do instead:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path node_modules -Recurse | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: This will fail with the path too long exception.